# can I extract the drivers in windows7 and use it in my Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, drivers

Hi I have a Windows 7 installer and I'd like to extract the built-in drivers of Windows 7 to be used in my windows xp install. Is it possible that I can make use of the drivers from windows 7?

I'd like to install windows 7 instead of Windows XP but the hardware isn't ready for Windows 7.

Drivers i'm interested is for Video and Sound. I also can't download drivers because i have a slow internet connection.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an experiment, I would like to know if any of them work in XP. Post back if you try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The driver models between the two operating systems are different, so Windows 7 drivers will not work on XP. You're best sourcing the correct drivers for XP from the manufacturer of the device.

Answer (score 0):

The system architecture for Windows Seven and Windows XP are diferent, this make a lot of diferences between these systems driver's development. If you try to install a Seven driver on a XP system or  vice-versa Windows will tell you that the driver is imcompatible with your installed Windows version.